# Parsing tab delimited file

Tags: data, streams, parsing

**Problem Description**

I have my data arranged in a tab delimited file and I'm trying to parse/access certain parts of it.

As an example, I'd like to extract the number of points and the sampling frequency as well as the time series which is saved like below (`>>` = tab, bullet = space):

[image: Data file]

Before and after this excerpt, there is a lot of other data that I don't need.

**Attempt**

I tried to find the position of interest in the file with the `Find` command and then readin the values with `Read`. I must be doing something wrong as an invalid data format error is thrown.

```
stream = OpenRead["test.txt"];
(* Find the line, that begins with "Number of points" *)
remarks = Find[stream,"Number of points"] (* now pointer at end of line *)

(* The next line is: Sampling frequency [Hz]    12000*)
Read[stream, {String, String, Real}, RecordSeparators->{"\t"}]
```

Output:

```
Out[256]= Number of points      100000
During evaluation of In[255]:= Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from test.txt. >>
Out[257]= $Failed
```

---

**Sample Data Set (tabs get replaced by 4xwhitespace)**

Here the position of interest would be e.g. "**2. dataset**". From there one I'd like to read the sampling frequency and the number of sample points, which then can be used to read in the {time, value} paired data.

```
1. dataset

Number of points        3
Sampling frequency  [Hz]    12000


Time [s]    Value
--------    -----

0.000000    0.8972
0.003333    0.9015
0.006667    0.9061

2. dataset

Number of points        4
Sampling frequency  [Hz]    12000


Time [s]    Value
--------    -----

0.000000    0.8972
0.003333    0.518
0.006667    0.8971
0.006667    0.8648

3. dataset

Number of points        3
Sampling frequency  [Hz]    12000


Time [s]    Value
--------    -----

0.000000    0.7716
0.003333    0.2674
0.006667    0.8899
```

Comment: Please add a relevant sample from your datafile so we can try and play with it to help you. It would be very hard to figure out exactly what is going wrong otherwise. Also, `readNumber` is not a built-in *Mathematica* function: where did you get it?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've added a sample but on stackexchange the tabs get replaced by whitespaces. I removed the reference to `readNumber` - I found it in an old Mathematica file with no source stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your sample data set (tabs replaced by spaces)**

```
str =

  "1. dataset

   Number of points 3  
   Sampling frequency[Hz] 12000
   Time[s] Value
   -------------
   0.000000 0.8972
   0.003333 0.9015
   0.006667 0.9061 

   2. dataset

   Number of points 4
   Sampling frequency[Hz] 12000
   Time[s] Value
   -------------
   0.000000 0.8972  
   0.003333 0.518   
   0.006667 0.8971   
   0.006667 0.8648      

   3. dataset 

   Number of points 3
   Sampling frequency[Hz] 12000
   Time[s] Value
   -------------
   0.000000 0.7716    
   0.003333 0.2674   
   0.006667 0.8899";
```

**Get all numbers**

Alternatives of digits, space and point

```
alt = Alternatives @@ Join[CharacterRange["0", "9"], {" ", "."}]
```

> "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | " " | "."

```
vec = ToExpression @ StringSplit @ StringJoin @ StringCases[str, alt]
```

> {1., 3, 12000, 0., ... 0.2674, 0.006667, 0.8899}

**Positions of datasets**

```
pos = 
  Transpose[{#, Append[Rest @ # - 1, Length @ vec]}] &[
     Flatten @ Position[vec, _Integer][[;; ;; 2]] - 1]
```

> {{1, 9}, {10, 20}, {21, 29}}

**Matrix of datasets**

```
(mat = Take[vec, #] & /@ pos) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Partition headers and points**

```
mat =
  Transpose[{
    mat[[All, ;; 3]],
    Map[Partition[#, 2] &, mat[[All, 4 ;;]]]}];

MatrixForm[%]
```

[image]

**Examples**

Get all points of second dataset

```
mat[[2, 2]]
```

> {{0., 0.8972}, {0.003333, 0.518}, {0.006667, 0.8971}, {0.006667, 
>     0.8648}}

Get all frequencies

```
mat[[All, 1, 3]]
```

> {12000, 12000, 12000}

Comment: Thanks a lot @eldo. I'm marking your reponse as an answer because it additionally allows to parse multiple datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your data in the form of a string, Mathematica has very powerful string operations that can parse the data.

I am not claiming that this is the most efficient method but it will work with your data (or possibly some minor tweaks).

Starting with your first example:

```
string1 = "Number of points 3

  Sampling frequency  [Hz]  12000


  Time [s]  Value
  --------  -----

  0.000000  0.8972
  0.003333  0.9015
  0.006667  0.9061";
```

First we will develop the code step by step and then create a function to do the entire procedure.

### Develop Code

**Step 1 - Split the string into lines**

```
string2 = StringSplit[data1, EndOfLine]
```

This creates a list with each line being a row.

**Step 2 - Extract the number of points**

Here (and in the other parts of the code) we will use `StringCases` to get the relevant data. This will output an empty list for each row that doesn't match. We will wrap this in `DeleteCases` to remove the empty list and finally use `Part` to remove the *curly brackets*.

```
numberPoints = DeleteCases[
   StringCases[string2, 
    "Number of points" ~~ Whitespace ~~ np : NumberString -> 
     ToExpression[np]], {}][[1, 1]]

(* "3" *)
```

**Step 2 - Extract the frequency**

```
frequency = DeleteCases[
   StringCases[string2, 
    "Sampling frequency  [Hz]" ~~ Whitespace ~~ freq : NumberString ->
      ToExpression[freq]], {}][[1, 1]]

(* "12000" *)
```

**step 3 - Extract the data**

This is the same as the previous steps except we will use `Flatten` to remove one *curly bracket*.

```
data = Flatten[
   DeleteCases[
   StringCases[string2, 
    time : NumberString ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
      value : NumberString -> {ToExpression[time], 
      ToExpression[value]}], {}],
  1]
(* {{"0.000000", "0.8972"}, {"0.003333", 
  "0.9015"}, {"0.006667", "0.9061"}} *)
```

### Define the function

Now that we have tested the individual steps a function is created to do everything.

```
extractData[string_String] := Module[
  {
   string2,
   numberPoints,
   frequency,
   data
   },

  string2 = StringSplit[string, EndOfLine];

  numberPoints = DeleteCases[
     StringCases[string2, 
      "Number of points" ~~ Whitespace ~~ np : NumberString -> 
       ToExpression[np]], {}][[1, 1]];

  frequency = DeleteCases[
     StringCases[string2, 
      "Sampling frequency  [Hz]" ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
        freq : NumberString -> ToExpression[freq]], {}][[1, 1]];

  data = Flatten[
     DeleteCases[
     StringCases[string2, 
      time : NumberString ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
        value : NumberString -> {ToExpression[time], 
        ToExpression[value]}], {}],
    1];

  {numberPoints, frequency, data}
  ]
```

### Test the function

Execute it on the test string

```
{numberPoints, frequency, data} = extractData[string1]

(* {"3", "12000", {{"0.000000", "0.8972"}, {"0.003333", 
   "0.9015"}, {"0.006667", "0.9061"}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear instructions. One problem arises if you have multiple sets that might have the same naming conventions (e.g. Number of points) as in the dataset of my edit. Is there a way to focus the selection to the first match below a certain unique marker such as "2. dataset"?